# Add a soft-break when generating HTML for excel document

Tags: html, excel

When I copy a table from Word or HTML with newlines in the cell, Excel converts each line in the text to individual cells. eg:

html:

```
<tr>
    <td>
    cell 1 line 1<br/>
    cell 1 line 2<br/>
    </td>
<tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    cell 2
    </td>
</tr>
```

is translated to the following 3 cells instead of 2 cells:

```
A1 -> cell 1 line 1
A2 -> cell 1 line 2
A3 -> cell 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the web I eventually found the answer in an old forum:

The solution I found is to add into a stylesheet:

```
br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
```